# how to use if / else condition in laravel 5.8 using

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to pass value from view to controller, but it not working.
it just triggers normal

my controller public

```
    function purchaseentryformsave(Request $request) {
      if ($request - > gst == '0') {
        $purchasen = new Purchase;
        $purchasen - > supplier_name = $request - > supplier_name;
        $purchasen - > bill_no = $request - > bill_no;
        $purchasen - > suppliers_master_id = $request - > suppliers_master_id;
        $purchasen - > party_id = $request - > party_id;
        $purchasen - > GSTIN = $request - > GSTIN;
        $purchasen - > bill_date = $request - > bill_date;
        $purchasen - > bill_entry_date = $request - > bill_entry_date;
        $purchasen - > total_bill_amount = $request - > total_bill_amount;
        $purchasen - > phone = $request - > phone;
        $purchasen - > pincode = $request - > pincode;
        $purchasen - > state = $request - > state;
        $purchasen - > address = $request - > address;
        $purchasen - > suppliers_unic_id = $request - > suppliers_unic_id;
        if ($purchasen - > save()) {
          $bill_no = $purchasen - > bill_no;
          $suppliers_master_id = $purchasen - > suppliers_master_id;
          $suppliers_unic_id = $purchasen - > suppliers_unic_id;
          $party_id = $purchasen - > party_id;
          $supplier_name = $purchasen - > supplier_name;
          $GSTIN = $purchasen - > GSTIN;
          $bill_date = $purchasen - > bill_date;
          $bill_entry_date = $purchasen - > bill_entry_date;
          foreach($request - > qty as $k => $p) {
            Billproduct::create(['product_name' => $request['product_name'][$k], 'bill_no' => $bill_no, 'suppliers_master_id' => $suppliers_master_id, 'suppliers_unic_id' => $suppliers_unic_id, 'party_id' => $party_id, 'supplier_name' => $supplier_name, 'GSTIN' => $GSTIN, 'bill_date' => $bill_date, 'bill_entry_date' => $bill_entry_date, 'qty' => $request['qty'][$k], 'HSN_SAC' => $request['HSN_SAC'][$k], 'sale_rate' => $request['sale_rate'][$k], 'MRP_rate' => $request['MRP_rate'][$k], 'purchase_rate' => $request['purchase_rate'][$k], 'part_no' => $request['part_no'][$k], 'dcs' => $request['dcs'][$k], 'gst' => strtoupper('18'), ]);
          }
          foreach($request - > qty as $g => $p) {
            Item_list::create(['supplier_name' => $supplier_name, 'product_name' => $request['product_name'][$g], 'qty' => $request['qty'][$g], 'purchase_rate' => $request['purchase_rate'][$g], 'MRP_rate' => $request['MRP_rate'][$g], 'sale_rate' => $request['sale_rate'][$g], 'part_no' => $request['part_no'][$g], ]);
          }
        }
      }
      elseif($request - > gst != '0') {
        $purchasen = new Purchase;
        $purchasen - > supplier_name = $request - > supplier_name;
        $purchasen - > bill_no = $request - > bill_no;
        $purchasen - > suppliers_master_id = $request - > suppliers_master_id;
        $purchasen - > party_id = $request - > party_id;
        $purchasen - > GSTIN = $request - > GSTIN;
        $purchasen - > bill_date = $request - > bill_date;
        $purchasen - > bill_entry_date = $request - > bill_entry_date;
        $purchasen - > total_bill_amount = $request - > total_bill_amount;
        $purchasen - > phone = $request - > phone;
        $purchasen - > pincode = $request - > pincode;
        $purchasen - > state = $request - > state;
        $purchasen - > address = $request - > address;
        $purchasen - > suppliers_unic_id = $request - > suppliers_unic_id;
        if ($purchasen - > save()) {
          $bill_no = $purchasen - > bill_no;
          $suppliers_master_id = $purchasen - > suppliers_master_id;
          $suppliers_unic_id = $purchasen - > suppliers_unic_id;
          $party_id = $purchasen - > party_id;
          $supplier_name = $purchasen - > supplier_name;
          $GSTIN = $purchasen - > GSTIN;
          $bill_date = $purchasen - > bill_date;
          $bill_entry_date = $purchasen - > bill_entry_date;
          foreach($request - > qty as $k => $p) {
            Billproduct::create(['product_name' => $request['product_name'][$k], 'bill_no' => $bill_no, 
        'suppliers_master_id' => $suppliers_master_id, 'suppliers_unic_id' => $suppliers_unic_id, 
      'party_id' => $party_id, 'supplier_name' => $supplier_name, 'GSTIN' => $GSTIN, 'bill_date' => 
      $bill_date, 'bill_entry_date' => $bill_entry_date, 'qty' => $request['qty'][$k], 'HSN_SAC' => 
     $request['HSN_SAC'][$k], 'sale_rate' => $request['sale_rate'][$k], 'MRP_rate' => 
    $request['MRP_rate'][$k], 'purchase_rate' => $request['purchase_rate'][$k], 'part_no' => 
  $request['part_no'][$k], 'dcs' => $request['dcs'][$k], 'gst' => $request['gst'][$k], ]);
          }
          foreach($request - > qty as $g => $p) {
            Item_list::create(['supplier_name' => $supplier_name, 'product_name' => $request['product_name'][$g], 'qty' => $request['qty'][$g], 'purchase_rate' => $request['purchase_rate'][$g], 'MRP_rate' => $request['MRP_rate'][$g], 'sale_rate' => $request['sale_rate'][$g], 'part_no' => $request['part_no'][$g], ]);
          }
        }
      }
      return redirect('/allpurchasesupplierlist') - > with('success', ' NEW PURCHASE ADDED SUCCESSFULLY .');
    }
    }
```

Comment: maybe the problem is that you used single quotes arounf 0. If you remove them does it work?

Comment: @Aless55 can you post answer

Comment: I can't understand your code, but there must be a problem in your if and else if, try debug your code outside of if or else if statement

Comment: @ Amir Jani can you guide me

Comment: @kerbh0lz can you edit may question code section im facing problem to edit it

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to edit in your code? Beautify it? Use proper indentation?

Comment: @Aless55 i removed single quotes around 0 it still not work

Comment: Whats the output of `dd($request->gst);`?

Comment: @sta i passed  0 from view i get array:1 [▼
  0 => "0"
] this. when i pass 18 i get array:1 [▼
  0 => "18"
]

Comment: `$request->gst;` is not a string then, its an array may be

Comment: @sta its an array im passing array from view

Comment: why do you want to compare an array to a string then?

Comment: @Aless55 then how i can compare input value

Comment: do you only need a single gst or do you have multiple gst? 
if you have only one you should change `gst[]`to `gst` in your blade. If you have multiple, you need to have a foreach loop in your controller

Comment: @Aless55 i have multiple gst

Comment: Then may be `foreach($request->gst as $key => $value) { if($value == "0") { codes here } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gst` is an **array**, so you need a foreach loop, like this :

```
foreach($request->gst as $key => $value) { 
  if($value == "0") { 
      // if 0, do something    
   } else {
     // if not 0, do something
   }
}
```